# Undefined reference with FreeType 2

Tags: linux, compilation, linker, freetype2

I am getting undefined reference error while building a simple example with [FreeType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeType) 2.

```
gcc `/usr/bin/freetype-config --cflags`  `/usr/bin/freetype-config --libs` a.c 
/tmp/ccuSpdkr.o: In function `main':
a.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `FT_Init_FreeType'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am on Ubuntu 12.10 x64. Package libfreetype6 & libfreetype6-dev are installed.

File `a.c` is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ft2build.h> 
#include FT_FREETYPE_H

int main() {
  FT_Library library;
  FT_Init_FreeType( &library );
  return 0;
}
```

I tried 2 step compilation, to make sure everything is on 64 bit:

```
> gcc -c `/usr/bin/freetype-config --cflags` a.c
> file a.o
a.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
> /usr/bin/freetype-config --cflags
-I/usr/include/freetype2
> /usr/bin/freetype-config --libs
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lfreetype -lz
> file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6.9.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6.9.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0x8ed223c2650372fc88b41fd348a72f03329adefa, stripped
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put the linker flags **after** the object and/or source files; instead of

```
gcc `freetype-config --libs` a.c
```

write

```
gcc a.c `freetype-config --libs`
```

Comment: whats the reason for having to do it this way?

Comment: The linker looks for symbols in the order their containing files are specified.